# Sinon mock returns once (never called)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I made an attendance tracker that uses slack and google sheets, and now I am trying to write the tests for it. I am currently struggling with mocking the timesheets.get() method. Keep getting the

> ExpectationError: Unexpected call: get(tester, Thu Jun 01 2017
>   00:00:00 GMT+0900)
>
> Expected get(tester, Thu Jun 01 2017 00:00:00 GMT+0900[, ...]) once
>   (never called)

error message

**code:**

```
execute(username, body) {
  let user = get username from body;

  let year = get year from body;

  let month = get month from body;

  let calculateMonthTotal = this._getMonthTotal(user, month, year, this.timesheets);
  this.slack.send(calculateMonthTotal);
}

static _getMonthTotal(username, month, year, timesheets) {
  const date = moment({year: year, month: month, day: 1});
  let totalWorkedHours = 0;
  while (date.month() == month) {
    const row = timesheets.get(username, date);
    totalWorkedHours += parseFloat(row.getWorkedHours());
    date.add('1','days');
  }
  return "month total is "+totalWorkedHours;
}
```

and the `timesheets.get()` is as follows:

```
get(username, date) {
  var sheet = this._getSheet(username);
  var rowNo = this._getRowNo(username, date);

  if (rowNo <= 4) {
    return null;
  }

  var row = sheet.getRange("A"+rowNo+":"+String.fromCharCode(65 + this.scheme.columns.length - 1)+rowNo).getValues()[0].map(function(v) {
    return v === '' ? undefined : v;
  });

  if (row) {
    return new TimesheetRow(username, date, row);
  }
}
```

And here is my **test**

```
describe('CommandMonthTotalSpec', ()=> {

  it('should call slack send method with expectMessage', () => {
    const username = "tester";
    const expectMessage = 'month total is 8';
    const body = "getMonthTotal "+username+" 2017/6";
    const date = moment({year: 2017, month: 5, day: 1});

    const row = new TimesheetRow(username, date, ["2017/06/01 00:00:00","2017/06/01 10:00:00","2017/06/01 19:00:00","","1","8","",""]);
    const slack = new Slack();
    const timesheets = new Timesheets();
    let mockTimesheets = sinon.mock(timesheets).expects('get').once().withArgs(username, date).onCall(0).returns(row);

    const command = new CommandMonthTotal(slack, null, timesheets);
    const mockSlack = sinon.mock(slack).expects('send').once().withArgs(expectMessage);

    command.execute(username, body);

    mockSlack.verify();
    mockTimesheets.verify();
  });
});
```

In the test I am passing two arguments, do not know why it is showing that error message. Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the `mockTimesheets` to the following solved the issue

```
let mockTimesheets = sinon.mock(timesheets).expects('get').atLeast(28).atMost(31)
  .onCall(0).returns(row)
  .onCall(1).returns(null)
  .onCall(2).returns(null)
  .onCall(3).returns(null)
  .onCall(4).returns(null)
  .onCall(5).returns(null)
  .onCall(6).returns(null)
  .onCall(7).returns(null)
  .onCall(8).returns(null)
  .onCall(9).returns(null)
  .onCall(10).returns(null)
  .onCall(11).returns(null)
  .onCall(12).returns(null)
  .onCall(13).returns(null)
  .onCall(14).returns(null)
  .onCall(15).returns(null)
  .onCall(16).returns(null)
  .onCall(17).returns(null)
  .onCall(18).returns(null)
  .onCall(19).returns(null)
  .onCall(20).returns(null)
  .onCall(21).returns(null)
  .onCall(22).returns(null)
  .onCall(23).returns(null)
  .onCall(24).returns(null)
  .onCall(25).returns(null)
  .onCall(26).returns(null)
  .onCall(27).returns(null)
  .onCall(28).returns(null)
  .onCall(29).returns(null)

;
```